# ExecuteReader como preencher os campos pela busca

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema para entender como faço para devolver os valores dentro do windows form (preencher os textbox,etc).

Esse método executa o data reader porém não sei como posso utilizar ele para preencher os campos.

```
public bool BuscarCliente(int id)
{
    using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string cmdBuscar = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE ID=@ID");

        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdBuscar, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", id));

            NpgsqlDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                //campos

            }
            else
            {
                //erro
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eu vi em alguns tópicos o pessoal utiliza desta forma:

Exemplo: `txtBairro.Text = reader[0].ToString();` Porém neste caso ele utilizou dentro do botão e no meu caso está em uma classe.

Como faço isso?

Classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Npgsql;
using System.Collections;

namespace GE
{
    class FDP
    {
        static string serverName = "localhost";
        static string port = "5432";
        static string userName = "postgres";
        static string password = "adm";
        static string databaseName = "GE";
        NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
        string ConnString = null;

        public FDP()
        {
            ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                       serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);

        }

        public bool InserirCliente(ArrayList p_arr)
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdInserir = String.Format("INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, ENDERECO, CIDADE, EMAIL, TELEFONE) VALUES (@NOME, @ENDERECO, @CIDADE, @EMAIL, @TELEFONE)");

                try
                {
                    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@NOME", p_arr[0]));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ENDERECO", p_arr[1]));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@CIDADE", p_arr[2]));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@EMAIL", p_arr[3]));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@TELEFONE", p_arr[4]));

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return true;
                    }
                }catch (NpgsqlException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
             }
         }

        public int UltimoRegistroCliente()
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdLast = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES ORDER BY ID_CLIENTE DESC LIMIT 1;");

                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdLast, conn))
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());   
                }

            }
        }

        public bool BuscarCliente(int id)
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdBuscar = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE ID=@ID");

                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdBuscar, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", id));

                    NpgsqlDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //campos

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //erro
                    }
                }
            }
        } 

        public bool DeletarCliente(int id)
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdDeletar = String.Format("DELETE FROM CLIENTES WHERE ID_CLIENTE=@ID");

                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdDeletar, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", id));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Crie propriedades na sua classe e passe os valores para ela, no seu formulário você cria uma instância da sua classe e chama o método `BuscarCliente`, após isso você pega o conteúdo das suas propriedades e joga para os textbox

Comment: @RobertoDeCampos cara não entendi muito bem, se puder responder de uma forma mais prática, agradeco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem aprofundar muito, basta pegar as colunas do dataReader:

```
public bool BuscarCliente(int id)
{
    bool retorno = false;
    using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string cmdBuscar = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE ID=@ID");

        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdBuscar, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@ID", id));

            NpgsqlDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                this.Nome = reader[0].ToString(); //onde 0 é índice da coluna do resultado da Query
                //ou
                this.Nome = reader["coluna_nome"].ToString();

               ... outros campos...

              retorno = true;
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Lá no evento do botão, pelo que entendi do seu código você vai fazer o seguinte:

```
    Cliente objCliente;
    private void buttonBuscarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           objCliente = new Cliente();
           if (objCliente.BuscarCliente(1)) //onde 1 é o código que será buscado. Aqui você deve colocar o campo de busca, com uma conversão de string para inteiro
           {
               //Buscou o cliente com sucesso
               textBoxNome.Text = objCliente.Nome;
           }
           else
           {
             //Erro ao buscar cliente
             textBoxNome.Text = "";
           }
    }
```

obs.: Não fiz nenhum tratamento de erros.

Comment: Essa parte de pegar a coluna eu entendi, quero saber quando uso a classe lá no botão buscar como ele preenche os campos

Comment: Se puder alterar a pergunta para que fique mais clara, mas era isso mesmo que estava precisando

Comment: Esse `this.Nome` esse Nome é o que? Eu preciso declarar ele para usa-lo? Como uso ele?

Comment: imagino que seja as propriedades do seu objeto, ou seja, da classe Cliente. Qualquer coisa, posta o código da sua classe Cliente

Comment: Irei complementar para que você possa ter melhor noção, 1s.

Comment: Problemas.. problemas? Eu sei que sim, mas me diz por cima quão ruim é rs

Comment: Você tem que fazer uma classe pra acesso ao banco de dados... e nela a conexão...métodos, etc... em outra classe, você cria o cliente, ou FDP no seu caso rsrs... a classe precisa de ter as propriedades que o cliente deve ter... nome, endereço, idade, etc... fica complicado te ajudar. Recomendo veementemente que estude um pouco mais antes de desenvolver. Sei que já está sem tempo mas ficar tentando fazer às cegas, só irá perder mais tempo.

Comment: Se eu implementar direto no botão o código consigo resolver?

Comment: Com certeza, o que disse é fato, estou fazendo algo realmente inútil dessa forma sei que preciso passar cada campo get;set tal.. só que tá foda.. agradeço pelas ajudas!

Comment: Não necessáriamente no botão, mas no Form, aí você consegue... basta colocar `textBoxNome.Text = reader["coluna_nome"].ToString();` chega a dói ver um negócio desses, mas, manda ver

Comment: É foda, faculdade não te ensina correto.. ai tu tem que fazer gambiarra.. nem sei se isso considera gambiarra.. mas obrigado de qualquer forma, sua resposta é a certa se eu estivesse fazendo certo também :)