# Erro consulta no banco de dados: here is no row at position 0

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no banco de dados ao chamar meu método e ocorre erro de row at position 0.

```
 public Cliente ConsultarCliente(long? id)
    {

        Cliente item;
        DAL acessarBanco = new DAL(); // Instanciando objeto acessar banco para realizar a conexão de dados.
        string sqlConsulta = $"Select ClienteId, Nome, CpfCnpj, Email, Senha From Estudo.Clientes Where ClienteId = '{ClienteId}' order by Nome asc"; //  variavel sqlConsulta para trazer todas os registros da tabela Clientes.
        DataTable dt = acessarBanco.RetDataTable(sqlConsulta);



        item = new Cliente
        {
            ClienteId = dt.Rows[0]["ClienteId"].ToString(),
            Nome = dt.Rows[0]["Nome"].ToString(),
            CpfCnpj = dt.Rows[0]["CpfCnpj"].ToString(),
            Email = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString(),
            Senha = dt.Rows[0]["Senha"].ToString()
        };

        return item;
    }
```

[Sou iniciante em c#]

Comment: A consulta traz algum resultado? Se executar a consulta diretamente no SQL, devolve-lhe resultados?

Comment: deveria checar se há registro antes de buscar o dado no dataTable... a primeira parte do código, demonstra uma forma melhor de executar o comando SQL: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247993/69359

Comment: Além disto tem o grave problema de segurança.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis deu certo aqui, na verdade estava fazendo a consulta errada.

string sqlConsulta = string.Format($"SELECT * FROM Estudo.Clientes WHERE ClienteId = {ClienteId}");, sendo que no meu parametro id estava vindo um id 2 por exemplo.

Ai na minha consulta eu deixei da seguinte forma:

string sqlConsulta = string.Format($"SELECT * FROM Estudo.Clientes WHERE ClienteId = {id}"); que é o id do parametro ai deu certo.

Comment: Você tem certeza que o `Id` deveria ser do tipo `long` e que a sua `DAL` deve executar qualquer texto que lhe for passada e não um `SqlCommand` com seus parâmetros definidos e tipados? Como disse o @Maniero, você tem graves problemas de segurança em sua aplicação.